# Status code 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJs and Ionic. Building a schedule app just to practice so please go easy on me.

I don't know why I'm getting this 405 response.  I tried to do a GET request with postman with the same information and it worked, but it doesn't work with my AngularJs code.

NOTE: I changed my access token (From UW) for safety.

Here's postman:

[image]

Here's my angular service:

[image]

and here's the error I'm getting when I run the ionic app:

[image]

Comment: You have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem. You can see in the error, there is preflight OPTIONS which returns the 405. You need to set up CORS support on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a cross origin policy problem.
Add these headers to your webserver and you should be all set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Don't forget to modify scope to suit your need.

== update ==

I just checked the link. The server is IIS 8.5

So I think this link you may find it helpful: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks, it is CORS problem. I followed the article here http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A 405 is a problem with the server angular is trying to talk to. Essentially, the request you made was matched to a route, but your server will not allow that route to execute.

Specifically, for your problem (and this is just my best assumption) ws.admin.washington.edu requires users to sign in. Your request is not authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran into this issue and we are indeed working on a server that requires users to sign in.